# Problem passing parameters via Iframe in IE

Tags: iframe, get, cross-browser, http-get

I'm trying to execute an HTTP GET from my website to another website that is brought in via iframe.

On Firefox, you can see in the source that the correct url is in the iframe src along with it's correct parameters-- and it works.

On IE, you can see in the source that the correct url is in the iframe src along with it's correct parameters-- and it doesn't work...

Is there something about IE that doesn't let you pass parameters through an iframe in the querystring?

I've tried refreshing the iframe in IE, I've tried refreshing my page & the iframe in IE, and I've tried copying the url and re-pasting it into the iframe src (forcing it to refresh as if I just entered it into the address bar for that iframe window). Still no luck!

Anyone know why this is happening, or have any suggestions to try to get around this?

**Edit:** I cannot give a link to this because the site requires a password and login credentials to both our site and our vendor's site. Even though I could make a test account on our site, it would not do any good for the testing process because I cannot do the same for the vendor site. As for the code, all it's doing is creating the **src** from the backend code on page load and setting the src attribute from the back end...

```
//Backend code to set src
mainIframe.Attributes["src"] = srcWeJustCreated;

//Front end iframe code
<iframe id="mainIframe" runat="server" />
```

---

**Edit:** *Problem was never solved. Answer auto accepted because the bounty expired. I will re-ask this question with more info and a link to the page when our site is closer to going live.*

---

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Here's a silly question: What happens when you try to navigate to that page with querystring in IE via the address bar (ie. no IFRAME)?

Comment: It works, it's just with the iframe that it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a link to the page we can use to investigate?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code in question.

Comment: I've passed a HTTP GET URL into an iframe on IE without any problems. It might be a security feature of doing it with a different domain though.

Comment: can you do a view source on the page and send the HTML output (changing whatever you feel is too sensitive).

Comment: i would suggest setting up a test page to spit out the request (headers etc), then point the iframe at that in both browsers. that'll give you some differences to research

Comment: I'm interested to know, did you sort your problem, since you marked an answer as correct?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue, but it's keeping the query strings, and removing everything after the # tag in the URL... has there been a solution to this on stack?? if not, I will start a new question thread for my particular issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the default security settings in IE query parameters are blocked in Iframes. On the security tab under internet options set your security level to low. If this fixes your problem then you know that is your issue. If the site is for external customers then expecting them to turn down their security settings is probably unreasonable, so you may have to find a work around.

Comment: The DNN Iframe Module works fine on both IE and Firefox when passing querystring parameters so this is definitely not the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Does the site you're having trouble with work when you set IE to low security?

Comment: Does anyone know *which* versions of IE this issue affects?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your site is **www.acme.com** and the iframe source is at **www.myvendor.com**.

IIRC, most domain-level security settings don't care about the hostname, so add a DNS CNAME to your zone file for **myvendor.acme.com**, pointed back to **www.myvendor.com**. Then, in your IFRAME, set the source using your hostname alias.

Another solution might be to have your Javascript set the src to a *redirector script* on your own server (and, thus, within your domain). Your script would then simply redirect the IFRAME to the "correct" URL with the same parameters.

Comment: +1 for anything involving DNS gymnastics. It makes the IT manager in me cackle with glee.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike's answer, the easiest solution in your case would be to use "parameter hiding" to convert all GET parameters into a single URL.

The most scalable way would be for each 'folder' in the URL to consist of the parameter, then a comma, then the value. For example you would use these URLs in your app:

> `http://example.com/app/param,value/otherparam,othervalue`
>   `http://example.com/app/param,value/thirdparam,value3`

Which would be the equivalent of these:

> `http://example.com/app?param=value&otherparam=othervalue`
>   `http://example.com/app?param=value&thirdparam=value3`

This is pretty easy on Apache with .htaccess, but it looks like you're using IIS so I'll leave it up to you to research the exact implementation.

EDIT: just came back to this and realised it wouldn't be possible for you to implement the above on a different domain if you don't own it :p However, you can do it server-side like this:

- Set up the above parameter-hiding on your own server as a special script (might not be necessary if IE doesn't mind GET from the same server).
- In Javascript, build the static-looking URL from the various parameters.
- Have the script on your server use the parameters and read the external URL and output it, i.e. get the content server-side. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381596/asp-equivalent-of-curl-not-asp-net) may help you with that.

So your iframe URL would be:

> `http://yoursite.com/app/param,value/otherparam,othervalue`

And that page would read and display the URL:

> `http://externalsite.com/app?param=value&otherparam=othervalue`

Answer (score 0):

If it suits you, you can communicate between sites with fragment identifiers. You can find an article here: http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2006/06/cross-domain-frame-communication-with.html

Answer (score 0):

What BYK said. I think what's happening is you are GETting a URL that is too large for IE to handle. I notice you are trying to send variable named src, which is probably very long, over 4k. I ran into this problem before, and this was my code. Notice the comment about IE. Also notice it causes a problem with Firefox then, which is addressed in another comment.

```
var autoSaveFrame = window.frames['autosave'];
// try to create a temp form object to submit via post, as sending the browser to a very very long URL causes problems for the server and in IE with GET requests.
var host = document.location.host;
var protocol = document.location.protocol;
// Create a form
var f = autoSaveFrame.document.createElement("form");
// Add it to the document body
autoSaveFrame.document.body.appendChild(f);
// Add action and method attributes
f.action = protocol + '//' + host + "/autosave.php"; // firefox requires a COMPLETE url for some reason! Less a cryptic error results!
f.method = "POST"
var postInput = autoSaveFrame.document.createElement('input');
postInput.type = 'text'
postInput.name = 'post';    
postInput.value = post;
f.appendChild(postInput);
//alert(f.elements['post'].value.length);
// Call the form's submit method
f.submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using an indirect method. Create a FORM. Set its action parameter to the base url you want to navigate. Set its method to POST. Set its target to your iframe and then create the necessary parameters as hidden inputs. Finally, submit the form. It should work since it works with POST.

Comment: Hey you! Yes the one who gave the minus one =) Please explain the reason so that I can learn something at a cost of 2 rep. points ;)

Comment: Heh, no problem. Your answer was confusing. You said to use a form with `method="get"` but that's going to use GET parameters which the OP is trying to avoid. Even if you use `method="post"` it's not gonna work well because you'd need buttons for all navigation. And the user would have to click a button at least once to load the iframe.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the GET/POST confusion warning =) And for your "button" objection, I would be happy to remind you that EVERY form can be submitted via JS ;)