# Issue with passing querystring parameters via Http Get to an iframe in IE

Tags: iframe, query-string, cross-browser, cross-domain, http-get

This is a follow up to my previous question: [Problem passing parameters via Iframe in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173137/problem-passing-parameters-via-iframe-in-ie). Which was never solved.

---

Here's the core of it:

> I'm trying to execute an HTTP GET from
>   my website to another website that is
>   brought in via iframe.
>
> On Firefox, you can see in the source
>   that the correct url is in the iframe
>   src along with it's correct
>   parameters-- and it works.
>
> On IE, you can see in the source that
>   the correct url is in the iframe src
>   along with it's correct parameters--
>   and it doesn't work...
>
> Is there something about IE that
>   doesn't let you pass parameters
>   through an iframe in the querystring?
>
> I've tried refreshing the iframe in
>   IE, I've tried refreshing my page &
>   the iframe in IE, and I've tried
>   copying the url and re-pasting it into
>   the iframe src (forcing it to refresh
>   as if I just entered it into the
>   address bar for that iframe window).
>   Still no luck!
>
> Anyone know why this is happening, or
>   have any suggestions to try to get
>   around this?
>
> As for the code, all it's doing is creating
>   the src from the backend code on page
>   load and setting the src attribute
>   from the back end...

```
//Backend code to set src
mainIframe.Attributes["src"] = srcWeJustCreated;

//Front end iframe code
<iframe id="mainIframe" runat="server" />
```

---

I've made a temporary account for you to login and see exactly what I mean. That way you can use firebug or any of your other debugging techniques to figure out why this isn't working rather than having me try to explain what's going on.

**EDIT: Changed the account credentials. Please use this one instead**
Username: matt
Password: globalbuying

Please follow [this link](http://www.oneworldunited.com/MyWorld.aspx) to get to the login page. One you login with the above credentials it will take you to the main backend page. Click the image on the left that says "Vacations", that will take to you a page with the iframe and will execute the Http Get from there.

If you need more details on what's going on in the behind code, etc., let me know and I'll post them.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Just trying to throw out my experiences with IE and IFRAMEs.  Have you tried refreshing/restore to default your internet explorer security settings?
Does IE say that you are in a Mixed-Zoned while you're viewing the page?  I'm trying to make sure your IFRAME isn't being treated as if its in the restricted zone in IE.  Can you try adding the IFRAME to your trusted zones and see if it works?
I know Mike made similar suggestions in your previous bounty, but I don't have any problems with query string parameters in IE.  The only time I've had trouble had been setting the security=restricted attrb.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After working my way through the HTTP requests with [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), comparing different browsers, I found that IE makes the request just fine, but fails to set any cookies in the `iframe`.

I also noticed that if I open that framed page by itself it does work. Even more so, after logging out again there, the iframed version works too. That's because it then already has a session cookie and the `iframe` no longer needs to set it.

It turns out that this is a known security restriction: IE blocks cookies in iframes. But this can be overcome with the use of the [Platform for Privacy Preferences (P3P)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P).

Here are a few links that should help you fix the problem. Starting off with another (answered) question on StackOverflow:

- [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)
- [Privacy in Internet Explorer 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343(VS.85).aspx)
- [IE Blocking iFrame Cookies](http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies)

Answer (score 0):

The example page you provided is working for me in IE8. The iframe is not as tall as in chrome, but it does have the correct page in it.

As an aside, please note that passing logon credentials via the query string is extremely unsecure and open to various exploits.

Comment: In the top right hand corner of the iframe does it say Sign In or Sign Out? Thanks for the heads up about the security-- Both our site and the vendor's site is going to be on SSL by the time we launch, so that will eliminate most of the security issues.

Comment: Ah I see now. You are right, it says Sign In. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ampersands in the iframe's URL are HTML-encoded (`&amp;`). 
I think that might cause IE to choke on identifying the param names. Does the problem still occur if you use plain ampersands in the URL?

If the encoding on the src attribute is happening implicitly, you might want to consider using a `Literal` control for testing purposes and set its `Text` property to the entire iframe tag to avoid any unwanted encoding.