# IE doesn't accept GET from iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

**Answer**:

It turns out that IE does not allow pages loaded in an iFrame to place cookies, which prevents me from storing a SESSION cookie to identify the users. The only way to prevent this is by implementing a P3P policy as explained by user Piskvor: [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer#389458)

---

**Question**:

I have a problem and have no idea why it's happening.

I have a page on domain1.net with a bit of javascript that scrapes a value from that page and then adds an iframe to that page with an src of a different domain like `http://www.domain2.net/login.php?id=123`. The login.php takes the id from the url, starts a PHP session and logs the user in by setting a `$_SESSION['id']` (please don't comment on how unsafe it is, it's a bit more complicated than that). If there is no id set in the url it returns a page telling the user to log in.

This all works fine on Chrome and Firefox but IE only show the "Please log in" page. If I then open the `login.php?id=123` page in a different tab it will log in, and if I then refresh the page on domain1.net it will show the user is logged in in the iframe.

Could someone shed some light on this? It seems like IE ignores the GET value in the url of the iframe.

For reference, this is my code on domain1.net:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://www.domain1.net/base/header', function (response, status, xhr) {
        var iframeid = response.match(/Profile\/Detail\/(.*?)"/);
        if (iframeid) {
            theid = iframeid[1];
            document.getElementById("addiframe").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://www.domain2.net/login.php?n=" + theid + "\" width=\"100%\" height=\"3000\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"braintrainer\"></iframe>";
        } else {

            document.getElementById("addiframe").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://www.domain2.net/login.php?logout\" width=\"100%\" height=\"3000\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"braintrainer\"></iframe>";
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="addiframe"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you're having this problem (check the first answer, you never know): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173137/problem-passing-parameters-via-iframe-in-ie

Comment: I've tried lowering my security level but it didn't make a difference sadly. It does seem like IE deliberately blocks it.

Comment: Oh, I found the following question asked by the same person. Apparently, IE passes the GET parameter correctly, but does not set cookies in iframes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329613/issue-with-passing-querystring-parameters-via-http-get-to-an-iframe-in-ie

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed seems to be the problem, and according to the asnwer it can be fixed with a p3p policy!

Comment: The reason is it's IE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that IE does not allow pages loaded in an iFrame to place cookies, which prevents me from storing a SESSION cookie to identify the users.

The only way to prevent this is by implementing a P3P policy as explained by user Piskvor: [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer#389458)