# Asp Classic cURL equivalent

Tags: php, curl, asp-classic

I need to basically forward post variables get the response and feed it back to an ajax post.

Essentially :
I have an ajax post that needs to post to an ASP file.
This file needs to forward these post variables to a PHP file and await a response.
The ASP file should then receive a response and relay that to the callback on the original ajax post.

I can write this quite quickly in PHP but am hoping for an ASP classic alternative as it is on a windows server with no PHP support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP equivalent of Curl (not ASP.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381596/asp-equivalent-of-curl-not-asp-net), found using [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=classic+asp+curl).

Comment: Thanks halfer. 
Thanks for this. How would I then add post variables to the code or print the results on the page?

Comment: I would guess `xhr.send myData` from one of those answers. Why not give it a go?

Comment: I your server http request object is called objRequest, then you could print it with `Response.Write objRequest.ResponseText`

Comment: Here's a link to an example with form variables http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3272/posting-form-data-to-a-web-page/2/

Comment: Thanks guys. Attempting now.

Comment: Hi Guys.

This ended up working for me. thanks for your help!

<%
set XmlObj = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 XmlObj.open "POST", "http://comain.co.za?var1=" & request.form("var1") & "&firstname=" & request.form("firstname") & "&action=" & request.form("action") , false
 XmlObj.send
 formatdata = XmlObj.responseText
 Response.write(formatdata)
 Set XmlObj = nothing
%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me. thanks for your help!

```
<% 
set XmlObj = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
XmlObj.open "POST", "domain.co.za?var1="; & request.form("var1") & "&firstname=" & request.form("firstname") & "&action=" & request.form("action") , false 
XmlObj.send formatdata = XmlObj.responseText 
Response.write(formatdata) 
Set XmlObj = nothing 
%>
```